# nodejs express error: Failed to lookup view "/pages/message" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This is weird because it has worked multiple times before but just now when i try to use `res.render` to send an html page to the client i just get the error from the title.  The html file is defenently in the views folder, so what could be the problem?

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/photos', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/pages/photo');
});

app.get('/message', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/pages/message');
});
```

Comment: @Saad look at the title :-)

Comment: is it throwing the error if you hit /photos?

Answer (score 2):

Template paths should be relative (to the `views` directory):

```
res.render('pages/photo');
res.render('pages/message');
```

The files should also end with `.ejs` as extension.

Answer (score 1):

1. you don't need to explicitly define views, it will automatically default to views folder.
2. make sure your directy structure is as follows:

> ```
> /
>    app.js <---the code above
>    /views
>        /pages
>           photo.ejs
>           message.ejs
> ```

and remove the '/' before views as stated by @robertklep